# Azure Application Gateway uses FIPS 140-2 validated module

Tags: azure, gateway, application, web-application-firewall

Does Azure Application Gateway uses FIPS 140-2 validated module for SSL/TLS offloading? Can we enable FIPS mode in Azure application gateway for TLS offloading?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, App Gateway uses FIPS compliant SSL/TLS cryptographic modules. You can also enforce an [SSL policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-ssl-policy-overview).

NIST publishes a list of vendors and their cryptographic modules validated for FIPS 140-2. Rather than validate individual components and products, **Microsoft certifies the underlying cryptographic modules used in Microsoft products, including Microsoft business cloud services**, with each new release of the Windows operating system. This enables customers to configure and use those services in a way that helps meet their information encryption and compliance requirements.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trustcenter/compliance/fips